AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested, how to resolve when '--device cpu' is suggested instead?
I'm currently grappling with a perplexing issue in my CUDA operations. Specifically, I'm encountering an 'AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested' error, despite intending to use '--device 0' for GPU processing. Instead, the error suggests opting for '--device cpu', which is unexpected and impedes the utilization of GPU acceleration.
This problem arose when I attempted to employ a pre-trained COCO model for object detection on an image within a Google Colab environment. The command I used was as follows:!python detect.py --weights '/content/weights/yolov9-e.pt' --conf 0.1 --source '/content/datas/thumb.jpg' --device 0
However, the encountered error thwarted my expectations, hindering the efficient utilization of GPU resources for faster processing. I'm now at a loss as to why this discrepancy exists and how to effectively address it to harness the GPU for enhanced object detection performance. Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on resolving this issue would be immensely appreciated. Thank you!"

Are you using a GPU runtime in Colab?
